# Desactivar botones al dar clic

Tags: javascript, botón

Mi problema consiste en que cuando le dé click a unos de los botones seleccionados dentro de esta variable:

```js
let btnsDogs = document.getElementsByClassName('btn')
```

Se desactiven los demas.

```js
let dogName = document.getElementById("nombre");
let dogGenr = document.getElementById("genero");

let vaccine = document.getElementsByName("vacuna");
let vaccineV2 = [...vaccine];

let imgRequest = document.getElementById("imgr");
let textRequest = document.getElementById("txtr");

let btnSend = document.getElementById("send");

let btnsDogs = document.getElementsByClassName("btn");
let btnsDogsV2 = [...btnsDogs];

class Dogs {
    constructor(nombre, genero) {
        this.nombre = nombre;
        this.genero = genero;
    }
}

class ElementsCreate {
    constructor(h2txt, drcimg) {
        this.h2txt = h2txt;
        this.imgDr = drcimg;
    }

    create() {
        let h2 = document.createElement("h2");
        let h2txt = document.createTextNode(this.h2txt);
        h2.appendChild(h2txt);
        imgRequest.appendChild(h2);

        let img = document.createElement("img");
        img.setAttribute("src", this.imgDr);
        imgRequest.appendChild(img);
    }
}

function create() {
    let paOne = document.createElement("p");
    let paTwo = document.createElement("p");
    //let paThree=document.createElement('p');

    let paOneRes = document.createTextNode(
        `El nombre de tu perro es : ${newDog.nombre}`
    );

    let paTwoRes = document.createTextNode(`El genero es: ${newDog.genero}`);

    paOne.appendChild(paOneRes);
    paTwo.appendChild(paTwoRes);

    textRequest.appendChild(paOne);
    textRequest.appendChild(paTwo);
}

function disable(item) {
    item.disabled = "disabled";
}

function arre(items) {
    items.addEventListener("click", () => {
        if (items === btnsDogsV2[0]) {
            let dogimg1 = new ElementsCreate(
                "Pastor Aleman",
                "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/9/94/Cane_da_pastore_tedesco_adulto.jpg"
            );

            dogimg1.create();

            btnsDogsV2[1];
        } else if (items === btnsDogsV2[1]) {
            let dogimg2 = new ElementsCreate(
                "Bull Dog",
                "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/a/a4/Racib%C3%B3rz_2007_082.jpg"
            );

            dogimg2.create();
        } else {
            let dogimg3 = new ElementsCreate(
                "Husky Siberiano",
                "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/c/ca/Siberian-husky.jpg"
            );

            dogimg3.create();
        }
    });
}

let newDog = new Dogs(dogName.value, dogGenr.value);

btnSend.addEventListener("click", create);

btnsDogsV2.forEach(arre);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Existe un atributo llamado `disabled` que deshabilita los botones. Podrías hacer que el botón escuche el evento `click` y cuando se dispare el evento agregarle el atributo `disabled` a los demás botones, por ejemplo:

```js
btnsDogs[0].addEventListener('click', (e) => {
  btnSend.setAttribute("disabled", "disabled")

  //agergar el atributo disabled a los demas botones
})
```