# ¿Cómo desactivar un botón en JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

tengo un problema, me gustaria que cuando presionara el boton y se obtenga el mensaje en pantalla el botón se desactivara

```
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <title>Cambiando contenido</title>
    </head>
    
    <body>
        <p id="segundo_texto">Javascript es...</p>
        <button id="segundo_boton">Enserio, no lo hagas</button>
    <body>
```

Este es mi codigo en ***JavaScript***

```
document.getElementById("segundo_boton").onclick = function () {
  document.getElementById("segundo_texto").innerHTML =
    segundo_texto.textContent + "Es genial";
};
```

Comment: ¿Responde esto a tu pregunta? [Desactivar botones al dar click](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/421119/desactivar-botones-al-dar-click)

Answer (score 2):

Todo lo que tienes que hacer es poner el atributo `disabled` en el botón después de hacer clic en él. Eso lo puedes hacer con `setAttribute`.

Comprueba el siguiente ejemplo basado en tu código:

```js
document.getElementById("segundo_boton").onclick = function() {
  document.getElementById("segundo_texto").innerHTML =
    segundo_texto.textContent + "Es genial";
  
  this.setAttribute("disabled", "disabled");
};
```

```html
<p id="segundo_texto">Javascript es...</p>
<button id="segundo_boton">Enserio, no lo hagas</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

puedes probar con el style-display:

```
document.getElementById("segundo_boton").onclick = function () {
    document.getElementById("segundo_texto").innerHTML = segundo_texto.textContent + "Es genial";
    document.getElementById("segundo_boton").style.display = "none";
};
```

Comment: Gaucho esto ocultará el botón. Creo que Felix sólo pretende desactivar el botón.

Comment: Cierto, interpreté que por desactivar quería ocultarlo. El atributo disabled es el que necesita. Thanks!